# Cancellation of Color fontspec font settings while defining microtype context

Tags: color, fontspec, microtype

I found a strange behavior of the `microtype` package. While using the command `\SetExpansion` to declare a microtype context with specific parameters, the color settings defined with the `fontspec` package are no longer available.

Here the code I was using:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{memoir}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{microtype}

\SetExpansion[
  context=MyExpansionContext,
  shrink=270,
  stretch=270
]{encoding=*}{}

\setmainfont{Linux Libertine}
\setsansfont[Color = FF0000FF]{Linux Biolinum}

\newcommand\Text{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, con- sectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.}

\begin{document}

{\sffamily This is a false-latin example:} \Text

\begin{microtypecontext}{expansion=MyExpansionContext} 
   {\sffamily This is a false-latin example:} \Text
\end{microtypecontext}


\end{document}
```

which gives as a result:

[image]

If I comment out

```
%\SetExpansion[
%  context=MyExpansionContext,
%  shrink=270,
%  stretch=270
%]{encoding=*}{}
```

the result is colored as desired, but, obviously, without the specified microtype parameters:

[image]

Comment: It works with XeLaTeX. This really isn't the place to report bugs, though.

Comment: @cfr It does not work with XeLaTeX, because XeLaTeX does not support font expansion. Anyhow, where do you suggest to post the topic?

Comment: Report it to the package(s) maintainer(s). I'd wait first to see if somebody can tell you which package is buggy or whether both are. But generally bugs should be reported to package maintainers. Usually the documentation will tell you where to report them or who to report them too. (Obviously, this only applies to maintained packages.)

Comment: What I meant, by the way, is that the colour works. Also, it isn't the expansion as such which is the problem. It is the use of the context. It is inserting lua commands directly, it seems. Moreover, the colour cannot be overridden using the ordinary colour commands in either XeTeX or LuaTeX (without an expansion context, obviously). That is, it is not just setting a default colour for sans. It is setting a come-what-may colour for sans.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`microtype` makes copies of the fonts (to avoid the error `! error:  (font expansion): font has been expanded with different stretch limit.`) with `\(pdf)copyfont`, and this looses all font features, not only the color but also e.g. `tlig` (ligatures) and `smcp` (small caps):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{luaotfload}  

\begin{document}

\font\testa={Arial:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;+smcp;color=FF0000FF;}
{\testa abc -- `` }  normal 

\pdfcopyfont\testb\testa

{\testb abc -- `` } normal

\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem can also be shown in context:

```
\starttext

\font\testa={Arial:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;+smcp;}
{\testa abc -- }  normal

\copyfont\testb\testa

{\testb abc -- } normal

\stoptext
```

So I will ask on the context list ...

### Edit

The answer from Hans Hagen is quite clear: `\(pdf)copyfont` works only on the `tfm` level and doesn't copy features like `tlig`, `smcp` and `color`. The code of microtype can't work correctly with open type fonts. Report the issue to the microtype maintainer.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I reported to the maintainer of the microtype package Robert Schlicht (w.m.l@gmx.net) the problem, hoping he will read the email!

Comment: @PaoloPolesana This has been fixed in `microtype` v2.7d. (My previous, now deleted comment was wrong.)